# How do I add click events to all buttons that have names starting with a certain string in C#?

Tags: c#

I am writing a simple calculator script for my C# programming class.  It will of course have buttons 0-9 that will update the output textbox to add the number of whatever button is clicked.  My problem right now that is I would rather not have to have 10 different click events in my script.  I would rather have a loop that cycles through the buttons that will add the same click event to each one and then decide what number to add to the output based on the button.

So right now, I have a click event for the "1" button which is this...

```
    private void btnNum1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtOutput.Text = Convert.ToString(txtOutput.Text + "1");
        }
```

This works fine, but, again, I would rather not have to do this 10 times.  How can I create a loop that prevents this?

The button names are btnNum1, btnNum2, btnNum3, etc.

Comment: You can use the `btnNum1_Click` event for the other buttons.

Comment: Is this WinForms?...or something else?...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the button text is just "1", "2" etc you could do this:

```
private void btnNum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button

    txtOutput.Text += button.Content.ToString();
}
```

Then just apply this event to all the buttons.

Also note you don't need `Convert.ToString()` as what you are trying to convert is already a string. Using `+=` also cleans up your code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this to wire-up all of the events in one go:

```
        for (var n = 0; n <= 9; n++)
        {
            var btn =
                this
                    .Controls
                    .Find("btnNum" + n.ToString(), false)
                    .Cast<Button>()
                    .First();
            var digit = n;
            btn.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                txtOutput.Text = digit.ToString();
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could enumerate the children controls of your Form/Control, look the type of controls which are type of Button and the name StartWith 'btnNum', with each of these buttons, add a Click event address to btnNum_Click().

Say if all your buttons are contained in a Panel named 'pnlButtons', you could loop all the children like this.

```
foreach (var control in pnlButtons.Controls)
{
    if(control.GetType() == typeof(Button))
    {  
        var button = control as Button;
        if (button .Name.StartWith('btnNum'))
        {
            button.Click += btnNum_Click;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Tag" property of the Button control and make an array of Buttons to subscribe to the same event. See sample below:

```
    void InitializeButtons()
    {
        Button btnNum1 = new Button();
        btnNum1.Text = "1";
        btnNum1.Tag = 1;

        //Button 2..8 goes here

        Button btnNum9 = new Button();
        btnNum9.Text = "9";
        btnNum9.Tag = 9;

        Button[] buttons = new Button[]{
            btnNum1, btnNum2, btnNum3, btnNum4, btnNum5, btnNum6, btnNum7, btnNum8, btnNum9
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].Click += Button_Click;
        }
    }

    void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        int value = (int)button.Tag;

        //Do something with value
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming WinForms, you can **recursively search** for buttons that start with "btnNum" and wire them up to a common handler like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FindButtons(this);
    }

    private void FindButtons(Control ctl)
    {
        foreach(Control ctrl in ctl.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.Name.StartsWith("btnNum") && (ctrl is Button))
            {
                Button btn = (Button)ctrl;
                btn.Click += btn_Click;
            }
            else if(ctrl.HasChildren)
            {
                FindButtons(ctrl);
            }
        }
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        txtOutput.Text = Convert.ToString(txtOutput.Text + btn.Text);
    }

}
```